# displaying tamil font in visual basic 6

Tags: vb6

I have used tamil font letters in vb6 text box. But it shows

```
?????
```

How to display Tamil font letters in visual basic 6 ?  please help me.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/193540

Comment: its very useful Rob. thanks.

Comment: But there is no reference to use tamil unicode font.

Comment: I am sorry I don't know anything about Tamil fonts. I do know that using fm20.dll allows Unicode to be shown in VB (one of my apps does it)

Comment: okay Rob.i will try it.